# Is $P\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i>\epsilon\}\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}P\{X_i>\frac{\epsilon}{n}\}$ true?

Tags: probability, statistics

$P\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i>\epsilon\}\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}P\{X_i>\frac{\epsilon}{n}\}$

where the $P$ is probability and $X_i$ is random variable.

If it is true, how to prove it?

Comment: Sum of $n$ numbers is greater than $\epsilon$ implies that at least one of them is greater than $\epsilon / n$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thank you, I have got it. For example, $\{X_1 + X_2 \geq \varepsilon\} \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{2}\{X_i\geq\varepsilon/2\}$